# Erlang throw statement not working in a function handler

Tags: erlang, try-catch, handler

I am trying to throw an error inside a function handler and catch it outside. It works fine if the handle is created localy. If I export the function and access it by its module name I get an {error,badarg}.

```
-module(mymodule).
-export([myfun/1]).


myfun(Any) -> throw(Any).


mytestfun1() ->
try
    FunHandler=fun myfun/1,
    FunHandler("myerr")
catch
    W:E -> {W, E}
end.
% returns {throw,"myerr"} as it should


mytestfun2() ->
try
    FunHandler=fun mymodule:myfun/1,
    FunHandler("myerr")
catch
    W:E -> {W, E}
end.
% returns {error,badarg} instead
```

I absolutely do not understand why this happens. Anybody got an idea?

Comment: It looks fine apart from the fact that the test functions are not exported. I replaced `-export([myfun/1]).` with `-compile(export_all).` so I could actually call the tests and it worked for me. Maybe you didn't reload the module after compiling it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of the Eclipse IDE Erlide. In its debug mode it replaces all function handles. In this case it does something wrong.
I posted the Bug under:
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3373292&group_id=58889&atid=489191